# Is financial assistance of CAD 3000 to an international student visiting Canada for research for less than 3 months considered taxable?

Tags: income-tax, canada, education

My son received an invitation from a university in Canada to do an internship for a period less than 3 months. He will be paid financial assistance of CAD 3000.00. Kindly clarify the following questions :

1. Whether financial assistance of this nature is taxable?
2. In case tax is applicable, what rate is applied?
3. How can a refund be claimed?

Comment: Is this his only Canadian income? What country is he coming from?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this pamphlet from the Candian Tax Authority](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/p113/p113-e.html#P84_4402), there are no specific gift taxes the giver of the gift.  If this is the only Canadian income he will be receiving over the course of the year [he doesn't make enough to be taxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Income_taxes_in_Canada). As such, there is no tax being paid, and there is no tax owed within Canada.

Whether or not the income is taxable in the *home* country is another matter.  For that, you would need to check your tax laws.